# Check if Querystrings are not visible on url

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, get, query-string

I have this code to check if query strings are present and echo contents based on the values.

The code is working if:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?position=&category=&country=
www.mywebsite.com/?position=position1&category=&country=
www.mywebsite.com/?position=&category=category1&country=
www.mywebsite.com/?position=&category=&country=country1
www.mywebsite.com/?position=&category=category1&country=country
.
.
and so forth.
```

but if the url is just www.mywebsite.com without querystring the parent else block is not executed.

My current code is:

```
<?php 
// args
    if ($_GET){
        if ($_GET['category'] && $_GET['country']) {
            $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'job_order',
            'meta_query'    => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'j_category',
                    'value'     => $_GET['category'],
                    'compare'   => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'j_country',
                    'value'     => $_GET['country'],
                    'compare'   => '='
                    )
                )
            );
        } elseif ($_GET['category']) {
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'job_order',
                'meta_key'      => 'j_category',
                'meta_value'    => $_GET['category']
                );
        } elseif ($_GET['country']) {
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'job_order',
                'meta_key'      => 'j_country',
                'meta_value'    => $_GET['country']
            );
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'job_order'
                );
        }
    } else{
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'job_order'
            );
    }
    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: and you are not looking for position in your code so thats irrelevant in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if ($_GET){
        if (isset($_GET['category']) && isset($_GET['country'])) {
            $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'job_order',
            'meta_query'    => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'j_category',
                    'value'     => $_GET['category'],
                    'compare'   => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'j_country',
                    'value'     => $_GET['country'],
                    'compare'   => '='
                    )
                )
            );
        } elseif (isset($_GET['category'])) {
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'job_order',
                'meta_key'      => 'j_category',
                'meta_value'    => $_GET['category']
                );
        } elseif (isset($_GET['country'])) {
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'job_order',
                'meta_key'      => 'j_country',
                'meta_value'    => $_GET['country']
            );
        }
    } else{
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'job_order'
            );
    }
```

You are not getting past the nested conditional statements. The final else gets executed as soon as there are no query strings.

And you should check if the value is set before getting it.